# how can I make pd.DataFrame() faster when converting raw image dataset to csv when creating csv from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In following code I am converting raw image dataset to csv in such a way that in the first column I am saving the name of the class (label) which in this case is folder name and then after that I am saving pixels in following columns.

Currently I am hierarchically stacking the label and pixel value and then I am appending it to a list because that's how I am able to make the dataframe as I desire but on each "df = pd.DataFrame(v)" it's taking a long time as I debugged the code using print() statements to check where it took long time to process. Isn't their any way I could make it faster and then append them to the ".csv" file?

```
# directory where your raw dataset of images is stored
root = 'test_case_images/Test_1/'

width = 224
height = 224

image_pixels = []
v=[]

# folder here will be the considered as class of image
for folder in os.listdir(root):
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, folder)):
        current_filepath = (os.path.join(root,folder))
        
#       reading image
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(current_filepath,filename))
    
#       fix image color
#         img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#       changing current image to grayscale
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
#       resizing image  
        img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))
    
#       flatten image
        value = img.flatten()
    
#       stacking the label and the pixel value
        stacked_value = np.hstack((folder,value))
        
        v.append(stacked_value)
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
        #  saving the dataframe 
        df.to_csv('data.csv', mode='a',header=False, index=False)
        
        v.clear()
```

Comment: There are too many variables here - number of images, size of images, disk io, etc.
Can you add the runtime for the dataframe creation and the datafram csv conversion to your question?

Comment: updated the title for question.